# Jenkins Pipeline Checkout SVN to custom workspace

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, svn-checkout

I'm writing an Jenkins Pipeline script at the moment (declarative). Basically like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        NLS_LANG = 'GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script itself works fine. But we now found out, that the jenkins checks out our SVN repository first to find the Jenkinsfile (Checkout in folder `workspace@script` in the `job Folder` > `C:\jenkins_home\jobs\<Projectname>\jobs\<Jobname>`).

Than the whole SVN is checked out again in an second step which I didn't wrote in the Jenkinsfile (Title: "`Declarative: SCM Checkout`").
It would be okay, if we could change the path of this checkout, because at the moment it checks out in a new created `workspace` folder in the `job folder`.

Here I have a screenshot from the console output of the pipeline job: [image]

How can the checkout in a custom workspace be achieved?

Preferably it would only checkout the Jenkinsfile on it's own on the first checkout, not the whole repository. 
I tried to change the `repository url` to the folder where the Jenkinsfile is saved (alone), but than the pipeline is also (only) checking out this folder on the second checkout.

Here I have a screenshot of the console output trying this: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To whom it may concern when coming around this question: use a ws('/path/to/dir') to allocate a different directory (see [Pipeline: Nodes and processes](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace))

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        NLS_LANG = 'GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8'
    }
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "Test"
                ws('/path/to/dir'){
                    //dosomething here, like "checkout scm"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```